# How to get cookie in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, cookies, octobercms

I've been made simple cookie. When user click button it save current time in cookie. My problem is that, I need to print that date and make a conditional.

I need to print cookie current time in default.htm or navbar.htm

This is what I have trying to add in

```
onStart() { 
   $cookie_time = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['get_date_time']);
}
```

and in navbar.htm

```
 {{ cookie_time }}
```

but it's not printed or anything. When I check in browse my site stores that cookie correctly.

Comment: Though this cause is not related to cookie, it is recommended to use Cookie facade to get cookie value like; `Cookie::get('get_date_time')`.
If the cookie is generated on frontend, specify the cookie name in `unencryptedCookies` in config/cookie.php file to prevent October to decrypt the value. See: https://octobercms.com/docs/services/request-input#cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not the best, the way you are getting cookie value is fine. Your problem is in how you pass the value to the twig template.

The syntax to assign to `$cookie_time` is wrong.
It should be like; `$this['cookie_time'] = ...`

Complete page code is this;

```
url = "/test"
==
public function onStart() {
    $this['cookie_time'] = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['get_date_time']);
}
==
{{ cookie_time }}
```

See [Hello World example in October document](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/pages#page-life-cycle).